# Creating a function returning an integer in given base

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a function which receives as input three integer numbers: `number`, `base` and `memory`. It must return the number `number` written as a vector of dimension `memory` which is the corresponding number in base `base`. Here is how I did it together with an example:

```
import numpy as np

def change_base(number,base,memory):
    result=np.zeros(memory)
    for i in range(base**memory):
        res=number
        for j in range(memory):
            v=int(res/base**(memory-(j+1)))
            res-=v*base**(memory-(j+1))
            result[j]=v
    return result

# example below: numbers from zero to 40 in base 3 with 6 digits available.

for i in range(40):
    print change_base(i,3,6)
```

As you can see, I did it manually. How can I do the same thing using some fancy already existing python command?

Comment: @Thomas Weller I want the digits to be fixed regardless of the number. And you are right about the time. But this is how I managed to solve the problem by myself. I'm open to corrections.

Comment: What should it do if `memory` is not big enough? `change_base(100, 3, 3)` currently returns `[11 0 1]`, so the first digit is not in the desired base.

Comment: @Barmar as you wish, I know it will never happen. Let's say that it must return the string "error: the number is too big"

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense!  What does it print?  Do you really want it to return floats?

Comment: @hpaulj Barmar method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of zeroes with the specified size. Then use [`numpy.base_repr()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html) to convert the number to the given base. That returns a string, you can convert that to a `numpy` array. Then overlay that on the array of zeroes.

```
import numpy as np

def change_base(number,base,memory):
    result = np.zeros(memory)
    converted = np.array(list(np.base_repr(number, base)))
    result[-converted.shape[0]:] = converted
    return result
```

Comment: It works perfectly. As a side note, I am wondering whether it is possible to use the `padding` command inside `np.base_repr` in some way in order to specify the memory there, without the need of using the following line.

Comment: I thought about that, but that adds a fixed amount of padding. There doesn't seem to be a way to say "pad until it's 6 digits".

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function in Python which does it for arbitrary bases.

There is a library called [`python-baseconv`](https://github.com/semente/python-baseconv). Your code would boil down to:

```
from baseconv import BaseConverter

for base in range(2,17):
    converter = BaseConverter('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:base])
    for i in range(40):
        print(converter.encode(i))
```

If you prefer sticking with NumPy, you can convert it to a "vector of dimension memory" by using `np.array(list(...))`:

```
from baseconv import BaseConverter
import numpy as np

def change_base(number,base):
    converter = BaseConverter('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[:base])
    s = converter.encode(number)
    return np.array(list(s))

for base in range(2,17):
    for i in range(40):
        print(change_base(i, base))
```

Comment: The question wants the result in a numpy array of a given size.

Comment: **It must return the number number written as a vector of dimension memory**

Comment: TY. You had to explicitly write '012'. I want it to practically work for any given base

Comment: @3sm1r: it does. Just provide more digits.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `"".join(map(str, range(base)))` will create that string for bases up to 10. It should be easy to write a function that creates the string for higher bases.